# Socket is called multiple times

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, sockets

I read other questions about this issue but didn't find a solution for the problem. I saw that you can removeListeners or move the socket code out of the click handler for example but it doesn't seem to fit my problem.

I am using sockets + ajax. My code logic goes as follows:

```
//client side
button.onclick = function () {Communicate(info);return false;};

function Communicate(info) {
   // ajax call
}

// server side -> receive ajax 
app.post("/...",function(req,res) {
    // do stuff (...)

    // send global socket call
    io.sockets.emit("GlobalCall",xx);

    // return ajax call to the user who triggered this
    res.send(...));

});

// client side again

socket.on("GlobalCall",function(x)) {
   // this is called twice sometimes for some reason... It should be called only once each time the server emits ...
}
```

As I commented on the code, the server emits only once but "GlobalCall" happens twice sometimes. 
Any help? Thank you

Comment: what is the problem? what is the error?

Comment: @robkuz Despite I only emit in the server side once, on the client side the socket.on("GlobalCall"...) is sometimes called twice

Comment: Can you add a console.log before socket.on at the front end and check how many times this code ran not when you emit but at the time of registering

Comment: @AsifSaeed Well it was on global scope so nothing that would matter. I found the problem and it is not directly related to sockets...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution wasn't really related to sockets. What was happening had to do with jquery animations that were executed twice for each assigned property. I didn't know that and didn't notice it. Wrong to blame the sockets.